# Jquery not working while process dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, drop-down-menu

The below code works for me

```
function gethotelsbydestination(dest_id) {

  $.ajax({
         url: "controller/gethotels.php",
         dataType: "json",
         data: "id=" + dest_id,
         success: function(data) {
              $("#divid").html("");
              $.each(data, function(index, item) {
                  var val = item.id;
                  var text = item.name;
                      $("#divid").append(
                      $('<option></option>').val(val).html(text)
                       );
              })
         }
   });
}
```

But when i use below code not returns anything.divv is the id of an dropdown passed from php page

```
function gethotelsbydestination(dest_id, divv) {

    var divdrp = "$('#" + divv + "')";
    $.ajax({
         url: "controller/gethotels.php",
         dataType: "json",
         data: "id=" + dest_id,
         success: function(data) {
             divdrp.html("");
             $.each(data, function(index, item) {
                 var val = item.id;
                 var text = item.name;
                 divdrp.append(
                      $('<option></option>').val(val).html(text)
                 );
             })
         }
    });
}
```

The problem is `var divdrp="$('#"+divv+"')";`
Any Solution please

Comment: what does the console output say about `divv`, which value does this have after running the script?

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: A bad formatted code is really hard to read. While you should do yourself a favor to indent your code correctly, it's the least thing you should do to support all the people that are willing to help you.

Comment: I have clearly explained the problem The problem is var divdrp="$('#"+divv+"')";

Comment: @mks Sure, and you also got the correct answer. But you still should take the time to to make a well formatted and easy to read question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't concatenate directly. Use this:

```
divdrp = $('#' + divv);
```

instead of this:

```
var divdrp = "$('#" + divv + "')"; //  it is not a jquery object
```

Comment: `"$('#"+divv+"')"` is not a syntax error, but results in a string instead of jQuery result set.

Comment: @t.niese ok .i will changed that